# Laravel Socialite: Laravel\Socialite\Two\InvalidStateException

Tags: php, laravel, callback, google-signin, laravel-socialite

I want to create social login using Google and Facebook. In the first step, I want to create Google Login. When I select the Google ID and Callback it shows me this error.

```
Laravel\Socialite\Two\InvalidStateException
http://localhost:8000/customer/login/google/callback?authuser=1&code=4%2F0AX4XfWgtwfNmX20WgsbTWXCO0joa1BrfjX0Iif1jqoxTqvT-AqwRVRgwyJwR95EuFlBx9Q&prompt=consent&scope=email%20profile%20openid%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&state=e7PCC5OnNvtkQ6e7GBquKsTtAjWYiIuMdFZ477Kt
```

URL :

```
Route::get('/customer/login/google/callback', 'handleGoogleCallback')->name('callback.to.google');
```

Controller :

```
 public function handleGoogleCallback() {
        try {
            $user = Socialite::driver('google')->user();
            dd($user);
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            throw $th;
        }
    }
```

```
'google' => [
        'client_id' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => 'http://localhost:8000/customer/login/google/callback',
    ],
```

```
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID="xxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET="GOCSPX-qzx7jVkboSS_xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

How to solve this problem??

Answer (score -1):

Your `state` is incorrect. `state` is a parameter that laravel-socialite added to auth request once you did /redirect. Seems like you trying complete auth operation two+ times from just only google.com request. Retry auth from /redirect request.

PS. sorry for my English

Comment: How to solve this. kindly give me refer code.